# Getting Error while calculation of two float numbers

Tags: c

I ran into a problem while calculating density of a box.
The output always comes out to be 0.00.
I tried type-casting but nothing worked.
Please help, I will be very grateful.

Here is the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
    {
        int l, b, h;
        float wt, vol;
        float den = 0.0;

        // Taking Length
        printf("Enter Length  ");  
        scanf_s("%d", &l);

        //Taking Breadth
        printf("\nEnter Breadth  ");
        scanf_s("%d", &b);

        //Takhing Height
        printf("\nEnter Heigh  ");
        scanf_s("%d", &h);

        //Calculating Volume of the Box
        vol = (l * b * h);

        //Printing Volume 
        printf("\nVolume Of The Box Is %.2f\n\n", vol);

        //Now taking mass of the box
        printf("Enter Weight  ");
        scanf_s("%f", &wt);

        //Calculating Density
        den = wt /(float) vol;

        //Printing Density
        printf("\nDensity of the Box Is %.2f\n\n", &den);
  }
```

The output of the program is as follows :

Enter Length   10

Enter Breadth   10

Enter Height   10

Volume Of The Box Is 1000.00

Enter Weight   5000

Density of the Box Is 0.00

Press any key to continue. . .

*Note*
Density = Mass(Weight)/Volume

Thanks :)

Comment: Please don't spam language tags. This looks like c.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Do not spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: Look carefully at the last argument in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall &v prints the address of the variable v in memory, we use this in scanf (if you're a beginner), so change your code to:

```
    printf("\nDensity of the Box Is %.2f\n\n", den);
```

Answer (score 2):

At least: wrong format specifier.

```
//                              double     address 
printf("\nDensity of the Box Is %.2f\n\n", &den);
```

Save time, enable all warnings.  A good well enabled compiler will warn about this mismatch.